# Triggering a function when a parent public method is called (like __call)

Tags: php, oop, pdo

A word before my question to say I am pretty new to OOP in PHP, and I'm very grateful to the site, and you all for reading - and sometimes answering beautifully (as you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5596895/php-database-class) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5622605/php-getting-a-reference-through-a-constructor), or even [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907018/building-a-factory-in-php)) and helping big time my late (sort of) improvement dealing with classes.

All my previous questions lead me today to this one:
**In a class extending PDOStatement, how can I trigger a default action each time one of the parent public methods is called?**

I can do this:

```
class genc_query extends PDOStatement{
  public function rowCount(){
    $this->myDefaultAction();
    return parent::rowCount();
  }
}
```

But as I need to change in the same way almost all of the native methods, I wonder if there's no way to trigger a function like __call() as if these methods were private (as it's not possible to make them private).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> as it's not possible to make them private

Indeed, this seems to be the case.

[ReflectionMethod can let you change the accessibility of a method](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionmethod.setaccessible.php), but it seems that it either doesn't work on internal methods (i.e. not user-defined) or it won't set public methods to protected/private.  It seems designed to make protected/private methods public instead.

It looks like your copy-and-paste boilerplate inside each method is going to be necessary.  Besides `__sleep` and `__wakeup`, there are only about three dozen methods, so it should only take you a few minutes.

Comment: All the functions needed are done actually, and all I needed were 8 functions... But when I look at it I just find it ugly

Comment: Yeah, it's ugly.  Welcome to PHP!

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of clear code, extend every method (means: overwrite and call `parent::method()` there), that you wants to have additional behaviour. Else there will be some day, where you or someone else may get really confused on what happens there.